# How to set a constant value for a field in webform (eg the prefered language)?

Tags: webform-civicrm

I'm creating several webforms in different languages to let people register to receive more information. I would like to set their preferred language to the language used in the form rather than the default (en_US).

I have similar needs for some custom fields.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I found is:

- add the field needed (eg. preferred field)
- go on form components and edit that field to enable only the option wanted (eg. spanish) and set it as the default
- set the widget as "hidden"

It's not bullet proof, as in theory, the visitor can still use tools like firebug and alter that field

Comment: make it "hidden - secure value" and it will be bulletproof.

Comment: that was the missing step, thanks coleman