# How to set the CMS language as the preferred language of the contact?

Tags: webform-civicrm, localisation

There is a way to force the language of a contact created via webform:
[How to set a constant value for a field in webform (eg the prefered language)?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9274/how-to-set-a-constant-value-for-a-field-in-webform-eg-the-prefered-language)

but I'd like to do it automatically, eg if I see the form as /fr/form it will set the preferred Civi language to fr, if the visitor is on /de/form it will be in german

Is this possible with webform civicrm?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer - but the PHP `$_SERVER` global variable contain the requested language code (e.g. `en_US`) (See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)).  `civicrm_option_value` stores the "Languages" option group, which provides a mapping from the language code to the language option value ID.

It seems like you could parse the requested language (`en` and `en-US` must be mapped to `en_US`), add an API call to `OptionValue.get` to get the correct ID value, and set the default value for preferred language.

Note that this is slightly different from what you're requesting - a French-speaking user on an English-localised web browser will get English, not French - but the concept should be applicable.

Comment: in my experience, the requested language is not that reliable, eg. lots are having the en software, despite having a different language. but we can easily get the drupal language in php, so that would work too

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to add some jquery -> that reads the URL - parses it - and then writes to the appropriate field on the webform based on whether it finds /de/ , /fr/ or /en/